Getting refresh_token null in springboot3.3 using oauth2 google
I am using Spring boot 3.3 with below configuration
Application.yaml :-----
spring:
security:
oauth2:
client:
registration:
google:
client-id: xxxx
client-secret: xx
scope: profile, email, openid
authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
client-name: Google
provider:
google:
#authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline
token-uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
user-info-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
Service class:----------------
@Service
public class OAuth2TokenService {
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

@Autowired
private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

public OAuth2AccessToken refreshToken(Authentication authentication) {
    String principalName = "";
     if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
         OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
         
         // Get the OAuth2User (OidcUser for OpenID Connect, OAuth2User for others)
         OidcUser oidcUser = (OidcUser) oauth2Token.getPrincipal();  // For OIDC (Google, etc.)
         
         // Get the principal's name (typically the name attribute)
          principalName = oidcUser.getName();  // You can also use oidcUser.getEmail(), oidcUser.getFullName(), etc.
         System.out.println( "Principal Name: " + principalName);
     }
    // Retrieve the OAuth2AuthorizedClient using the registrationId
    final var registrationId = "google";
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(registrationId, principalName);
    
    // Get the refresh token from the authorized client
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = authorizedClient.getRefreshToken();

    **if (refreshToken == null ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No refresh token found");
    }**


Find related post , now my issue resolved now
Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token
authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline
Needs to add prompt ,access_type params in your request.
